# How to calculate $\pi$

Tags: limits, circles, infinity, pi

If I were to convert a quarter circle into isosceles triangles, I would find I have a triangle with 2 sides of length r (radius), and the other length is to be found, I'll call it "a".

If I split the quarter circle (90 degrees) into n segments, I would find the angle opposite to side "a" would be equal to $\frac{90}{n}$. Given the triangle is isosceles, the two angles opposite the sides of length r would be $\frac{1}{2}\times (180-\frac{90}{n})$, which simplifies to ($90 - \frac{45}{n}$).

Hence, the sin rule means;

$\frac{a}{sin(\frac{90}{n})}=\frac{r}{sin(90-\frac{45}{n})}$

This is the same as;

$a = \frac{r \times sin(\frac{90}{n})}{sin(90-\frac{45}{n})}$

If I wanted to find the sum of these sides, I would simply multiply it by n, given there are n sides, so;

$a = n\times\frac{ r \times sin(\frac{90}{n})}{sin(90-\frac{45}{n})}$

I could use this to calculate $\frac{1}{4}$ of the circumference of a circle. Given a circle has infinite sides, n should be infinite. Therefore;

As $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(\frac{90}{n})=0$, and;

$\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}(\frac{45}{n})=0$, then;

$a = n \times \frac{r \times sin(0)}{sin(90-0)}$, so;

$a = n \times \frac{r \times 0}{1}$, which means;

$a = n \times 0$, which means that because any number times 0 is 0, a must be equal to 0. Hence, as this is a quarter of the circumference, the circumference must be equal to $4 \times 0 = 0$.

As $circumference = \pi \times d$, then $\pi = \frac{circumference}{d}$. As circumference is 0, $\pi = \frac{0}{d}$, so $\pi = 0$.

Of course, it defies logic for circumference to always be equal to 0, and therefore it similarly defies logic for pi to be equal to 0, so where have I gone wrong in getting to this answer?

Comment: Have a look at one of the examples illustrated in this video. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SoU2ePlqG5M&t=13s

Comment: Problem is that $\;\displaystyle\lim_{n\to \infty} \left( n\cdot\frac{ r \cdot sin(\frac{90}{n})}{sin(90-\frac{45}{n})}\right) \ne \lim_{n\to \infty} \left( n\right) \cdot \lim_{n\to \infty} \left( \frac{ r \cdot sin(\frac{90}{n})}{sin(90-\frac{45}{n})}\right)\,$ because the RHS is undefined.

Comment: @FreeRadical Hmm. That video doesn't seem authoritative. Among other things, the narrator thinks that infinitesimals are responsible for $1 = 0.999\ldots$

Comment: @Theophile: Hmm probably that is why he lost the challenge

Answer (score 4):

Your work in computing the limiting value of $a$ is basically the same as the following, more obvious mistake:

$$ 1 = \lim_{n \to \infty} 1
= \lim_{n \to \infty}\left( n \cdot \frac{1}{n} \right)
\mathrel{\color{red}=} n \cdot \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n}
= n \cdot 0
= 0 $$

Comment: Okay, I see. However, when I replaced r with 1 and computed $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} n\times\frac{ 1 \times sin(\frac{90}{n})}{sin(90-\frac{45}{n})}$, it gave me an answer of $\frac{90}{sin90}$, which is 90. I times this by 4 and get 360, and given $\pi = \frac{circumference}{2r}$, then surely $\pi = \frac{360}{2} = 180$. As you can see, I once again get a really weird result.

Comment: With regards to my previous comment, I fear the calculator was using radians not degrees, hence explaining the really weird result.

Comment: @PhysicsGuy123 Don't forget the degree sign when working with degrees! Your conclusion would then be correct: $\pi = 180^\circ$.